# Logical operators inside if funtion

Tags: r

Need help help in logical operators. Here the result pr should be "A" right? Not sure why it is returning "B"

```
cn <- c("A","B")
pk <- c("A")
wh <- c("F")
if(pk %in% cn && is.null(wh))
 {
   pr <- c("A")
 } else {
   pr <- c("B")
}
```

Comment: Why? 0 is not in cn, and also wh is not null.

Comment: `is.null(wh)` is False, so with `&&` it should be `else`, i.e. `pr == "B"`.

Answer (score 0):

`cn` is a character vector, there is no way ever that your `pk %in% cn` could evaluate to being `TRUE` because `pk` is a numeric vector of length 1 (could also be used as logical but in no way could it be a character vector).

**edit:
after you changed it, now your second condition can never be true, because as long as wh is not an empty vector ( it has `"F"` in it), you can never have `is.null(wh)` evaluate to `TRUE`.